# What is the expectation of a random variable satisfying some conditions?

Tags: order-statistics, numerical-integration

How to find the expectation E[X.I(Y<x,X<x)], where X and Y are independent random variables with respective cumulative distribution functions F(.) and G(.) respectively. x is a positive value. Does the following idea make sense?
\begin{align*}
  E[X.I(Y<x,X<x)]
  &=\int_{0}^{x}zP(Y<x)dF(z)\\
  &=\int_{0}^{x}zG(y)dF(z)\\
   \end{align*}
Please provide hint.

Comment: Why do you have $G(y)$ rather than $G(x)$?  You could take it outside the integral if $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. I should have write the expression as $$ \int_{0}^{x} z G(x) dF(z)$$.  If it can be taken outside, then the expectation become $G(x) \int_{0}^{x} z  dF(z)$, right?

Comment: I also suspect the integral should be from $-\infty$ if $X$ and $Y$ can take negative values

Comment: The variables take non-negative values only.

Comment: Hint: begin with the definition of expectation, which is a *double* integral.